# Can't connect Mikrotik OpenVPN Client to Linux server

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, openvpn, mikrotik

Greethigs!

I would really appreciate any help!

For the last two days i cannot make Mikrotik router connect to Debian 10 OpenVPN server.

For each connection attempt router shows the following error message:

```
Status: terminating... - could not add address: netmask cannot be /0 (6)
```

Here's my config:

**Client:** Mikrotik RB2011UiAS-2HnD-IN / RouterOS: 7.1b2 / 6.46.8 (tried both firmwares)

```
"White" IP: 195.111.111.2/30    Gateway: 195.111.111.1

[admin@MikroTik] > /interface print                                                                                                                                     
Flags: R - RUNNING; S - SLAVE      
   #      NAME            TYPE      ACTU  L2MT  MAX-  MAC-ADDRESS          
   0  R   ether1-gateway  ether     1500  1598  4074  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:03    
   1  RS  ether2          ether     1500  1598  4074  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:04    
   2  RS  ether3          ether     1500  1598  4074  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:05    
   3  RS  ether4          ether     1500  1598  4074  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:06    
   4   S  ether5          ether     1500  1598  4074  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:07    
   5   S  ether6          ether     1500  1598  2028  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:08    
   6   S  ether7          ether     1500  1598  2028  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:09    
   7   S  ether8          ether     1500  1598  2028  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:0A    
   8   S  ether9          ether     1500  1598  2028  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:0B    
   9   S  ether10         ether     1500  1598  2028  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:0C  
  10      sfp1            ether     1500  1598  4074  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:02    
  11  RS  wlan1           wlan      1500  1600  2290  D4:CA:6D:00:E0:0D    
  12      office          ovpn-out                    02:FF:F4:DF:C3:9A    
  13  R   bridge1         bridge    1500  1598        D4:CA:6D:00:E0:0D

[admin@MikroTik] > /interface ovpn-client print                                                                                             
Flags: X - disabled; R - running     
 0    name="office" mac-address=02:F2:F2:2F:CC:1A max-mtu=1500 connect-to=195.222.222.2 port=1198 mode=ip protocol=tcp user="mikrotik" password="" profile=default     
      certificate=cert_2 verify-server-certificate=no auth=sha1 cipher=aes256 use-peer-dns=no add-default-route=no 

[admin@MikroTik] > /ip route print                                                                                                          
Flags: D - DYNAMIC; X - DISABLED, I - INACTIVE, A - ACTIVE; C - CONNECT, S - STATIC, m - MODEM        
  #       DST-ADDRESS        GATEWAY         D    
     AS   0.0.0.0/0          195.111.111.1  1    
     DAC  192.168.47.0/24    bridge1         0    
     DAC  195.111.111.2/30   ether1-gateway  0


[admin@MikroTik] > /ip firewall nat print     
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid; D - dynamic     
 0    chain=srcnat action=masquerade dst-address=0.0.0.0 out-interface=ether1-gateway log=no log-prefix=""
```

**Server:**
Debian 10 + Xen 4.11 bridged

```
# ip addr

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master xenbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:2f:6b:20:2e:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:2f:2b:20:2e:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 195.222.222.2/30 brd 195.222.222.1 scope global eno2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: xenbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:2f:2b:20:2e:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.48.1/24 brd 192.168.48.255 scope global xenbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vif1.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master xenbr0 state UP group default qlen 32
    link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 10.101.0.1/24 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf:

local 195.222.222.2
port 1198
proto tcp
dev tun1
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key  
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh.pem
data-ciphers AES-256-CBC
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA1
topology subnet
server 10.101.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp_tcp.txt
client-config-dir ccd
push "route 192.168.48.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.47.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.47.0/24 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
;comp-lzo
;max-clients 100
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log     /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 6
;mute 20

#/etc/openvpn/ccd/mikrotik

iroute 192.168.47.0 255.255.255.0 10.101.0.2
ifconfig-push 10.101.0.2 10.101.0.1 255.255.255.252

# iptables -S

-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1198 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i xenbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o xenbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# iptables -t nat -S

-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.48.0/24 -d 192.168.48.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.48.0/24 -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.48.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 195.222.222.2
```

OpenVPN server log:

```
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=127869 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=127918 Re-using SSL/TLS context
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=127965 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1623 D:1210 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=127977 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1623 D:1450 EF:123 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=128002 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1559,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_SERVER,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,key$
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=128010 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1559,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,cipher AES-256-CBC,aut$
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=128035 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=128045 TCPv4_SERVER link local: (not bound)
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=128053 TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=132062 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER READ [14] from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0$
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=132100 195.111.111.2:34720 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720, sid=d0dc4e5c 860c785f
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=132124 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER WRITE [26] to [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ 0 ] pid=$
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=136840 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER READ [22] from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 0 ]
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=183931 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER READ [116] from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=1 DATA len=102
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=184699 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER WRITE [1196] to [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ] pid=1 DATA len=1170
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=184741 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER WRITE [1078] to [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=2 DATA len=1064
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=190449 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER READ [22] from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ]
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=235548 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER READ [22] from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 2 ]
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=841342 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER READ [1282] from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=2 DATA len=1268
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=841519 195.111.111.2:34720 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=Easy-RSA CA
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=841600 195.111.111.2:34720 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=mikrotik
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=841809 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER WRITE [77] to [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ 2 ] pid=3 DATA len=51
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=846294 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER READ [22] from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 3 ]
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=891974 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER READ [303] from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=3 DATA len=289
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=892064 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER WRITE [259] to [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ 3 ] pid=4 DATA len=233
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896730 195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER READ [22] from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 4 ]
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896755 195.111.111.2:34720 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896771 195.111.111.2:34720 [mikrotik] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896788 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.101.0.2, IPv6=(Not enabled)
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896826 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 OPTIONS IMPORT: reading client specific options from: ccd-tcp/mikrotik
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896884 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 MULTI: Learn: 10.101.0.2 -> mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896894 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 MULTI: primary virtual IP for mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720: 10.101.0.2
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896902 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 MULTI: internal route 192.168.47.0/24 -> mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896911 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 MULTI: Learn: 192.168.47.0/24 -> mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896967 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896978 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 Outgoing Data Channel: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896987 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=896995 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 Incoming Data Channel: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=943781 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER READ [56] from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=4 DATA len$
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=943836 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=943858 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 SENT CONTROL [mikrotik]: 'PUSH_REPLY,route-gateway 10.101.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-resta$
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=943876 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 4 ]
2020-11-17 01:53:40 us=943918 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER WRITE [156] to [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=5 DATA len$
2020-11-17 01:53:41 us=251 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 TCPv4_SERVER READ [22] from [AF_INET]195.111.111.2:34720: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 5 ]
2020-11-17 01:53:41 us=76161 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 Connection reset, restarting [0]
2020-11-17 01:53:41 us=76196 mikrotik/195.111.111.2:34720 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
2020-11-17 01:53:41 us=76272 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved that issue simply. But it took me two days.

Just had to remove this line in server's OpenVPN config file:

```
topology subnet
```